# How to get writable sdcard data location in Android

Tags: c#, android, maui

I need to get the following location in C# MAUI project for Android:

`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test.dir/files`

`com.test.dir` is Android package ID. In Qt for Android I can get it by the following way:

```
QString s = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation);
```

When Android device without SD card is connected to PC using USB, this directory can be opened in PC file manager, for example:

`This PC\Galaxy Tab A8\Tablet\Android\data\com.test.dir\files`

Android application can create files/directories here, and all these operations are visible from connected PC.

Is it possible to get this directory in C# MAUI project?

Comment: Should be `GetExternalFilesDir(null)` https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/android.content.context.getexternalfilesdir?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13

Comment: Thanks. Exact syntax is `Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null)?.AbsolutePath;`, compiled only if `ANDROID` is defined. In my case returned `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/comm.app.id/files`